# is my escape function enough?

Tags: php, escaping

I can't use mysql_real_escape_string since we are not using mysql (but [drizzle](http://www.drizzle.org/) instead), so I made a custom escape function. Please tell me if this is fine or not

```
function escape($value)
{
  $return = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); ++$i) {
    $char = $value[$i];
    $ord = ord($char);
    if ($char !== "'" && $char !== "\"" && $char !== '\\' && $ord >= 32 && $ord <= 126)
      $return .= $char;
    else
      $return .= '\\x' . dechex($ord);
  }

  return $return;
}
```

i will be primarily using this for $value's in several SQL's

Comment: To answer such a question one have to know what the heck that "drizzle" is.

Comment: If you are using a database library, use that library's escape function. Building your own is never a good idea.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel drizzle is a mysql branch, so pretty much a DB, almost like mysql, but lighter.

Comment: @Pekka the drizzle-php thing does not has its own escape function

Comment: @Pekka http://docs.drizzle.org/

Comment: Can you show some code how you are using this in PHP? If it doesn't come with an escape function, chances are it doesn't need one.

Comment: I've never used Drizzle before, but I was browsing the documentation. What about the `drizzle_escape_string` function? http://docs.drizzle.org/libdrizzle/query.html?highlight=escape#drizzle_escape_string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you should be using [`drizzle_escape_string`](http://docs.drizzle.org/libdrizzle/query.html?highlight=drizzle_escape_string#drizzle_escape_string)

> the drizzle-php thing does not has its own escape function

Zend seems to say that [it does](http://devzone.zend.com/1504/getting-started-with-drizzle-and-php/) (quite a long way down the page).

Comment: i feel embarassed, i searched so much before making one of my own :(